# Angular 4 Cannot Authorize API

Tags: angular, authorization, token, secret-key

I am building an Angular 4 Project and would like it connected to the handwriting.io API.

My question is how do I proceed with the secret and key authorization? I have never worked with API's that require authentication so I am kinda clueless.
I keep getting unauthorized error.
How do I use the key and secret to connect to the API?

SO far My code is this:

```
import { HandWriteAPIPage } from './../../e2e/app.po';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
  private apiKey: string = '2ND4YD74W5Y5Z8NC';
  private apiSecret: string = '65T65J5V850RWEHE';
  private apiURL: string = 'https://api.handwriting.io/handwritings'

  data: any = {};

  constructor(private http: Http){

    this.getData();
    this.getHandWrite();
  }

  getData(){
    return this.http.get(this.apiURL)
      .map(res => res.json());
  }

  getHandWrite(){
    this.getData().subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your API requests to the handwriting API requires a basic authorization header attached to each request. You will have to attach these credentials to the header before making the request.

Angular has a class in the Http module which can be used to achieve setting custom headers / authorization:

Your code may look like the following:

```
import { HandWriteAPIPage } from './../../e2e/app.po';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
  private apiKey: string = '2ND4YD74W5Y5Z8NC';
  private apiSecret: string = '65T65J5V850RWEHE';
  private apiURL: string = 'https://api.handwriting.io/handwritings'

  data: any = {};

  constructor(private http: Http){

    this.getData();
    this.getHandWrite();
  }

  getData(){
      let headers: Headers = new Headers();
      headers.append("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(this.apiKey + ":" + this.apiSecret)); 

      return this.http.get(this.apiURL, {
        headers: headers
      })
      .map(res => res.json());
  }

  getHandWrite(){
    this.getData().subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
    });
  }
```

You may want to set your header in a separate method in this service. But I hope this helps.

Comment: Lastly you may want to change your API keys once you have this resolved ;)